# Scattering in Shallow Bound States - Suppression of Matrix Element

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, scattering, s-matrix-theory, matrix-elements

In Weinberg's *Lectures on Quantum Mechanics*, given the S-matrix
$$S_{\beta \alpha}=\delta(\beta-\alpha)-2 \pi i \delta\left(E_\beta-E_\alpha\right) T_{\beta \alpha}\tag{8.8.4}$$
where
$$T_{\beta \alpha} \equiv\left(\Phi_\beta, V \Psi_\alpha^{+}\right)=\left(\Phi_\beta, T\left(E_\alpha+i \epsilon\right) \Phi_\alpha\right)\tag{8.8.5}$$
it is commented that if the two particle scattering "in" state labeled $\alpha$ has azimuthal quantum number $\ell$ other than $0$, the matrix element can be suppressed by factors of $k^\ell$. I suppose $k$ would be the wave number, but I don't know how this fact follows from scattering theory. What could be the cause for this suppression in the matrix elements?
For more details, consult section 8.8 on shallow bound states of the textbook.